# Is there a better way to make this?

Tags: html, css, web

is there a better way to make the html icon and the progress bar so that the bar is in the center of the icon?

in the css file I am using 'float: left;' so they are next to each other

if you are able to help me thank you in advanced

[image]

HTML

```
    <div class="skills-container">
        <div class="my-skills">My skills</div>
    
    <div class="skill-row">
            <div class="icon">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" enable-background="new 0 0 50 50" xml:space="preserve">
                    <path fill="#E44D26" d="M47.025,0.02l-4.014,44.958L24.974,49.98L6.981,44.984L2.974,0.02H47.025L47.025,0.02z"/>
                    <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="29.542,9.211 25,9.211 24.981,9.211 21.917,9.211 11.172,9.211 11.304,10.691 12.659,25.891   25,25.891 25,25.889 31.771,25.889 31.132,33.041 24.981,34.699 23.371,34.27 23.371,34.27 18.832,33.046 18.44,28.646   12.905,28.646 13.676,37.305 22.273,39.69 22.273,39.69 22.328,39.705 24.973,40.439 24.998,40.434 24.998,40.433 36.287,37.303   36.371,36.371 37.665,21.853 37.8,20.373 24.981,20.373 24.981

,20.375 17.703,20.375 17.199,14.727 21.917,14.727 24.981,14.727   25,14.727 29.542,14.727 38.305,14.727 38.412,13.487 38.663,10.691 38.796,9.211 "/>
                </svg>
         </div>
         <div class="skill-level">
             <div class="progress"></div>
         </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.skills-container {
    width: 35%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #393E46;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
}

.my-skills {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    font-size: 33px;
    color: #EEEEEE;[![enter image description here][1]][1]
}
.icon {
    margin: 3%;
    float: left;
}

.skill-level {
    width: 75%;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 5%;
    border: 2px solid purple;
    border-radius: 75px;
    float: left;
}
 .progress {
    width: 86%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 75px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: ░░░░░░░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░│░╔╗╔╦══╦═╦═╦╗╔═══╗░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░│░║╚╝╠╗╔╣║║║║║║╔══╝░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░│░║╔╗║║║║║║║║╚╣╚══╗░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░│░╚╝╚╝╚╝╚╩═╩╩═╩══╗║░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░╔══╝║░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░│░█████████▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░│░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░░░░░──────────────────────░░░░░░░░░░░░░░

Comment: Maybe something like that? Because your icon is too small for the progress bar. A box containing the two might look better. You can also center this box too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making .skill-row class flex makes logo and progress bar set next to each other and setting align-items: center; help you to set progress bar vertically center to icon.

```css
.skills-container {
  max-width: 1190px;
  background-color: #393e46;
  margin: auto;
}

.my-skills {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 33px;
  color: #eeeeee;
}
.skill-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.skill-level {
  margin-left: 30px;
  width: 75%;
  height: 25px;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  border-radius: 75px;
}
.progress {
  width: 86%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 75px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills-container">
  <div class="my-skills">My skills</div>
  <div class="skill-row">
    <div class="icon">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" enable-background="new 0 0 50 50" xml:space="preserve">
        <path fill="#E44D26" d="M47.025,0.02l-4.014,44.958L24.974,49.98L6.981,44.984L2.974,0.02H47.025L47.025,0.02z" />
        <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="29.542,9.211 25,9.211 24.981,9.211 21.917,9.211 11.172,9.211 11.304,10.691 12.659,25.891   25,25.891 25,25.889 31.771,25.889 31.132,33.041 24.981,34.699 23.371,34.27 23.371,34.27 18.832,33.046 18.44,28.646   12.905,28.646 13.676,37.305 22.273,39.69 22.273,39.69 22.328,39.705 24.973,40.439 24.998,40.434 24.998,40.433 36.287,37.303   36.371,36.371 37.665,21.853 37.8,20.373 24.981,20.373 24.981

,20.375 17.703,20.375 17.199,14.727 21.917,14.727 24.981,14.727   25,14.727 29.542,14.727 38.305,14.727 38.412,13.487 38.663,10.691 38.796,9.211 " />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="skill-level">
      <div class="progress"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```